# Compiling php5.5.30 on AIX

Tags: php, aix

When I compiling php5.5.30 on AIX, after configuration, run `gmake`, always get error:

`ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .floorf
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .ceilf`

php-config is

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php5.5.30     --enable-sockets --enable-ftp --enable-soap --enable-zip     --enable-pdo --enable-phar --enable-mbstring --enable-gd-native-ttf     --enable-bcmath --enable-xmlwriter --enable-xmlreader     --enable-simplexml --enable-libxml --with-curl     --with-iconv --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir --with-png-dir     --with-bz2 --with-mcrypt --with-openssl --with-kerberos     --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd     --with-zlib --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php5.5.30     --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=php-fpm --with-fpm-group=staff`

Comment: Maybe this question has more chance of getting an answer on Super User, Server Fault or Unix & Linux sites of StackExchange.

Comment: note that the tag `aix` has only 152 followers here on S.O.  I'm surprised that aix has `gmake`. . . . . I have seen better AIX answers in the unix group on ITToolbox.com. You have to register and find the group (+join group to post question), but you're more likely to get help there. Also ibm has AIX specfic support forums. You'd do well to dig into them too. Good luck.

Comment: 'floorf' should come from /usr/lib/libm.a You might try to execute `export LIBS=-lm` before the compilation...

Comment: I've run into similar problems on AIX 7.1. ceilf and floorf are not defined in /usr/lib/libm.a in 7.1 (they are in 6.1), though on 7.1 libm.a does contain other ceil and floor variants. ceilf and floorf are defined in libC.a (-lC, note the upper-case C) so you could try that.

Comment: The comment by @softwariness should be used as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to install rpm's from the official IBM AIX Toolbox. Source Packages are available also, just in case.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/alpha.html